# Replace From One Character Up To But Not Including Another Character

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following output, and I want to replace everything starting with the "/" following the IP address up to, but not including, the first instance of the word vlan.  How can accomplish that?

```
sy3-fa-c3r801-lb-3b.audc1.xxxxx.com address 192.168.1.2/30 allow-service { default  traffic-group Common/traffic-group-local-only vlan Common/vlan-HA }
sy3-ibr-lb-1a.audc1.xxxxx.com address 160.34.63.68/29 floating enabled traffic-group Common/traffic-group-1 unit 1 vlan Common/vlan13 
sy3-ibr-lb-1a.audc1.xxxxx.com address 160.34.63.193/26 floating enabled traffic-group Common/traffic-group-1 unit 1 vlan Common/vlan23 
sy3-ibr-lb-1a.audc1.xxxxx.com address 192.168.1.1/30 allow-service { default  traffic-group Common/traffic-group-local-only vlan Common/vlan-HA }
sy3-ibr-lb-1a.audc1.xxxxx.com address 160.34.63.194/26 traffic-group Common/traffic-group-local-only vlan Common/vlan23 
sy3-ibr-lb-1a.audc1.xxxxx.com address 160.34.63.69/29 traffic-group Common/traffic-group-local-only vlan Common/vlan13 
sy3-ibr-lb-1b.audc1.xxxxx.com address 160.34.63.68/29 floating enabled traffic-group Common/traffic-group-1 unit 1 vlan Common/vlan13 
sy3-ibr-lb-1b.audc1.xxxxx.com address 160.34.63.193/26 floating enabled traffic-group Common/traffic-group-1 unit 1 vlan Common/vlan23 
sy3-ibr-lb-1b.audc1.xxxxx.com address 192.168.1.2/30 allow-service { default  traffic-group Common/traffic-group-local-only vlan Common/vlan-HA }
sy3-ibr-lb-1b.audc1.xxxxx.com address 160.34.63.195/26 traffic-group Common/traffic-group-local-only vlan Common/vlan23 
sy3-ibr-lb-1b.audc1.xxxxx.com address 160.34.63.70/29 traffic-group Common/traffic-group-local-only vlan Common/vlan13
```

Comment: Are you looking for something that will (using the first line as example) look like: `sy3-fa-c3r801-lb-3b.audc1.xxxxx.com address 192.168.1.2/ [REPLACEMENT] vlan Common/vlan-HA }` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\(.*[0-9]\)\/.* \(vlan.*\)/\1REPLACEMENT\2/' file
```

Match the first occurrence of `/` by its preceding number and the first occurrence of `vlan` by its space character.

Comment: Actually, this matches the **last** `[0-9]\/` and the **last** `<space>vlan` – which in the given example also happen to be the first.

Comment: Technically speaking, yes (the greedy `.*`).

Answer (score 0):

Might work also

```
sed -r 's/vlan/\x01/;s/(([0-9]{1,3}[.]?){4})\/.*\x01/\1...vlan/' file
```

Use a placeholder for the first `vlan` to circumvent `sed`'s greediness. And yes, there is a small vulnerability from the "optional" dot in the IP. Use an more sophisticated regex for it if need be.